# Why can't I loop through my disk size?

Tags: powershell

This is very simple code that I can't seem to make function properly
I want to find all the drives on my computer then, want to display their size.

```
$disks = gwmi win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"} | Select DeviceID
foreach ($i in $disks){
$i
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq "$i"} | Select Size
}
```

When displaying $i, the output is exactly as I need it I even used a Read-Host to check them one by one and every drive letter is displayed. Unfortunetly, the command to Select the size does not return anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more intuitive to me to iterate through disks themselves, not their IDs, i.e.

```
$disks = gwmi win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"}
foreach ($disk in $disks)
{
    $disk.Size
}
```

`$disk | Select Size` also works, and, as Joey neatly complemented, whole thing is equivalent to

```
gwmi win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"} | Select -ExpandProperty Size
```

Comment: You're just emulating a `select -expandproperty size` there.

Comment: +1 Indeed, thanks for pointing out. I somehow never noticed that switch.

Comment: Well, *technically* it's equivalent to `($disks = gwmi win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"}) | select -exp size`, since you're still left with the `$disks` variable ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know powershell really, but I figured I'd mess around with your script.  Looks to me like the "$i" is wrong - instead use $i.DeviceID (without the quotes).  Whole script that seems to work for me:

```
$disks = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"} | Select DeviceID
foreach ($i in $disks){
$i.DeviceID
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq $i.DeviceID} | Select Size
}
```

Another option would be to skip the iteration:

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"} | Select DeviceID, Size
```

Algorithmically I would recommend this based on execution -- the approach you are taking now iterates over all of the devices two times inside loops (basically O(n^2)).  The "other option" above only iterates over them once.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use server side filtering when ever you can using the Filter parameter instead of the Where-Object cmdlet (client side filtering), it performs faster. The latter gets ALL objects first and only then performs the filtering.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceId='$($i):'" | Select-Object Size
```